# Удаление и копирование между страницами - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как на jquery можно сделать удаление блока и подгрузку вместо него (можно копирование) с другой страницы?
Использовать php для способа буфферизации не хочется.

Например, есть на странице *1.html* один div с содержимым. А на странице *2.html* другой блок div.

Как без применения php на первой странице удалить блок и вместо него скопировать блок со второй страницы?

Comment: Назовите хотя бы одну причину, по которой вы не хотите использовать php? Потому что остальные способы, не только, возможно **не рабочие**, но и довольно **сложные** в реализации

Answer (score 1):

Через ajax:

```
$.get("/2.html #novosti", function(data) {
    $("#novosti").replaceWith(data);
});
```